# How to avoid very last assertion (if I understood it properly)

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, frequency-analysis, system-verilog-assertions

I'm following http://verificationguild.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&p=5019 to check period of particular signal.
That method works perfectly, but at very end of simulation if assertion is kicked by posedge (active edge) it basically fails cause there is no next edge.

Please consider following example: testbench clock is running at 2MHz, update clock (on which I've assertion written) is running at 5Hz (period 200ms) for particular test.
Lets say simulation is running for 500ms of time, Assertion kicked at time 400ms fails.

How should I avoid this situation?

Comment: Which simulator are you using?

Comment: I'm using irun (Cadence simulator)

Comment: If your using `disable iff (!rst_n)` in your assertion then reset before finishing the sim.

Comment: @Munkymorgy: Thanks, that would have been a good idea. However it has been answered with elegant way at https://forum.verificationacademy.com/forum/verification-methodology-discussion-forum/systemverilog-and-other-languages-forum/29612-how-avoid-very-last-assertion-if-i basically drop the use of implication operator fixes it cause I already have ##1

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the `assert_report_incompletes` variable.  Create a file called `irun_variables.tcl` that contains:

```
set assert_report_incompletes 0
run
```

Then start irun with the `-input irun_variables.tcl` option.  This will make it so incomplete assertions are not marked as failures.